# what is the difference between indefinite pronoun and impersonal pronoun?

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns, indefinite-pronouns

what is the difference between indefinite pronoun and impersonal pronoun?

indefinite pronoun

ex- Somebody pushed me from behind.

impersonal pronoun

ex- One should always speaks truth.

here **somebody** and **one** both refer back nonspecific person or things

then what is the difference between them?
or both are same

Answer (score 1):

Some sources do actually call this usage of "one" indefinite, so I'm not sure if any consistent terminology is in use.  Still, there are two notable differences between "one" and "someone".

**1) In meaning.**

> Someone pushed me.

You can't replace this with "One pushed me", because "one" means "people in general" (or occasionally "I").

You could say "one pushed me" if it was short for "one of them pushed me", but it would have be contextually clear: "Three men were standing behind me.  One [of them] pushed me."

> One should always speak the truth.

This means "People [in general] should always speak the truth".  It would be a bit odd to say "Someone should always speak the truth", because it is not clear whether you mean people in general or a particular individual (as in "Someone has stolen my pen").  But "someone should speak the truth" could work in some contexts.

**2) Grammatically.**

"Someone" is rarely repeated (and when it is, it's often for humorous effect) when it refers to the same referent.  Instead, a personal pronoun is substitued for the second and subsequent references.

So, instead of "Someone pushed me, and I would like to know who someone is, so that I can have a word with someone", we say "Someone pushed me, and I would like to know who it was, so that I can have a word with them."

Personal and impersonal pronouns, by contrast, are repeatable without any awkwardness: "He pushed me, and I want to ask him why he did it."

"One" is a borderline case, though: British English always favours repetition, while American English speakers often (not always) treat it more like an indefinite pronoun (replaceable with "he" or "they"), as in these examples from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_(pronoun)):
One can glean from this whatever he may.
If one were to look at himself, his impression would be...
where British English would have "One can glean from this whatever one may" and "If one were to look at oneself, one's impression would be...".